# SQL - Get and update value from next record by Foreach on select result

Tags: sql, lead

I do not have much experience in SQL so my question is probably simple:
On the result of a SELECT query, I need to UPDATE all records so that each record gets a value that is in the next record, as shown in the screenshot.
I would love to have an easy and ready code.

Note: I have the attached code:

```
SELECT ID, Title ,IDxNumber,  LEAD(IdxNumber,1,0) Over(order by idxnumber) AS HotCode from MYTABLE
```

It works to **display** the data. But I want to **update** the data in the HotCode column in the table itself, not just display them.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest _not_ doing this update, as the hot code column depends on the data in the rest of the table, and is therefore _derived_ data.  Just run this query whenever you need the hot code.

Comment: You may be right in general, but I want to execute the query at least in parts of the table where I know HotCode is not used at all (this is a field that is almost never used). So I would love an answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?  Any answer would probably depend on this.

Comment: This is SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL Server, we can use an updatable CTE.  Assuming the `HotCode` column already exist in your table:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LEAD(IdxNumber, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY idxnumber) AS HotCodeNew
    FROM MYTABLE
)

UPDATE cte
SET HotCode = HotCodeNew;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I don't understand correctly but something like this?

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET something = table.something
FROM (
SELECT ID, Title ,IDxNumber,  
       LEAD(IdxNumber,1,0) Over(order by idxnumber) 
       AS HotCode FROM MYTABLE
) table
WHERE MYTABLE.id = table.id
```